# Fetch Data from Database and display it in a Screen

Tags: abap

I am a beginner in ABAP. I want to know what is the best way to fetch data from a database table and display each line in one screen with two buttons (back and next), so that every time only one line of the table is displayed (as in an online QCM).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question is way too broad for the Q&A format of SO. Other than "get the appropriate training", what kind of answer would you expect?

Comment: >  I want to know what is the best way to fetch data from a database table and display each line in one screen with two buttons (back and next), so that every time only one line of the table is displayed (as in an online QCM).

"The best way"-questions are always opinion based.
Snice vwegert already said, that this question is too broad, I want to add, that it might also be opinion based and therefore not really an SO question-format.But, as long You do not have a sample-code, which You can refer to, there will also be only answers, which might theoretically cover someones opinion.